# Removing header and footer from webview

Tags: android, header, android-webview, jsoup, footer

I want to remove the header and footer before loading the content to the web view. This code isn't working .

```
package com.wiseme;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GridView grid;
    public WebView webView;
    public int pos;

    String[] desc = { "Who We Are", "What We Do", "Entrepreneur",
            "Scholarship", "Admission", "Internship", "Industrial Visit",
            "Project", "Buy or Sell Projects", "Free Training",
            "College Registration", "Information", "Feedback", "Contact" };

    int[] imageId = { R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy,
            R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy,
            R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy,
            R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy,
            R.drawable.dummy, R.drawable.dummy

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitymain);

        GridDesign adapter = new GridDesign(MainActivity.this, desc, imageId);
        grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                pos = position;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, webView.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                MainActivity.this.finish();

                            }
                        }).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
    }

}
```

Web view class

```
package com.wiseme;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class webView extends MainActivity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        WebView webView;
        webView = new WebView(this);

        WiseWeWebClient myWebClient = new WiseWeWebClient();
        webView.setWebViewClient(myWebClient);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);




        switch (pos) {
        case 0:
            webView.loadUrl("http://wisewe.com/who-we-are/");
            break;
        case 1:
            webView.loadUrl("http://wisewe.com/what-we-do/ ");
            break;
        case 2:
            webView.loadUrl("http://wisewe.com/entrepreneur/ ");
            break;
        case 3:
            webView.loadUrl("http://wisewe.com/scholarship/");
            break;
        case 4:
            webView.loadUrl("http://wisewe.com/college-admission/ ");
            break;
        case 5:
            webView.loadUrl("http://wisewe.com/internship/");
            break;
        case 6:
            webView.loadUrl("http://wisewe.com/industrial-visit/");
            break;
        case 7:
            webView.loadUrl("http://wisewe.com/project/ ");
            break;
        case 8:
            webView.loadUrl("http://wisewe.com/sell-projects/");
            break;
        case 9:
            webView.loadUrl("http://wisewe.com/free-training/");
            break;
        case 10:
            webView.loadUrl("http://wisewe.com/college-registration/");
            break;
        case 11:
            webView.loadUrl("http://wisewe.com/branch/wise-we/");
            break;
        case 12:
            webView.loadUrl("http://wisewe.com/branch/feedback/");
            break;
        case 13:
            webView.loadUrl("http://wisewe.com/contact-us/");
            break;
        }
        setContentView(webView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        webView.this.finish();
    }
}
```

WiseWeWebClient

```
package com.wiseme;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WiseWeWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:var footer = document.getElementById('footer'); footer.parentNode.removeChild(footer); var header = document.getElementById('header-full'); header.parentNode.removeChild(header);");
    }

}
```

Header .......

[image]

Footer......

[image]

Those are all updated to latest. Still I couldn't remove header and footer.

Comment: screenshot of the footer and header ?

Comment: I have posted in the question now. Have a look

Comment: to the header the the "wise we" with the google search bar, and the footer the social network buttons ?

Comment: Yes those are things I want removed.

Answer (score 1):

According your screen-shot, you are using multiple `Jsoup Library`. Use only one of them.
Use [this link](http://jsoup.org/download) for download `Jsoup Library`.

Comment: I have just imported them. Even then i cant use jsoup functions.

Comment: @KiranManjunath - its working at my side. Just use jsoup-1.8.2.jar .

Comment: Okay wait let me check

Comment: @KiranManjunath - Great (y)

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshots and the website, it's a web/html issue : you want to remove some DOM elements of your page. As you want the header/footer on mobile device but not in your app, you will have to run some javascript when the page is loaded :

1. Create a custom WebViewClient to listen to `onPageFinished`

   ```
   public class WiseWeWebClient extends WebViewClient {

       @Override
       public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           view.loadUrl(url);
           return true;
       }

       @Override
       public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           view.loadUrl("javascript:var footer = document.getElementById(\"footer\"); footer.parentNode.removeChild(footer); var header = document.getElementById(\"header-full\"); header.parentNode.removeChild(header);");
       }

   }
   ```
2. set the WebClient to your webview

   ```
   WiseWeWebClient myWebClient = new WiseWeWebClient();
   webview.setWebViewClient(myWebClient);
   WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
   webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   ```

Comment: You need to escape the quotes here - `getElementById("footer")` and here  `getElementById("header-full"`

Comment: Oh okay let me check.

Comment: Still getting the error (String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote)

Comment: Got it. It should be in a single line.

Comment: @KiranManjunath replace `\"` by `'` (simple quote)

Comment: Even then the header and footer appear :( I'll update all the results in my question wait..

Comment: I don't know why but, `footer.parentNode.removeChild(footer);` did not worked for me. Instead,
`footer.style.display='none';` works fine.